# Ajax return Partial View lost Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, partial-views

I have a main view which has master layout contains all javascripts, ie jQuery DatePicker control, etc.

Inside this main view, I use Ajax.BeginForm(.....) which contains a partial view. And in my controller, if validation fails it returns that partial view. (also the UpdateTargetId in Ajax has been set the Id of the section contains that partial view.)

My error bullets display correctly. However I found I seems to loose the javascript after that. For example my calender/date picker stops working and it comes a normal input box.

What could be the reason?

Thanks a lot!!

**Here is the code:**

My main view contains one Ajax form. And inside there are 2 partial views. The 2nd one has datepicker inputs.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionXXX", "ControllerYYY", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "main"        
}))
{
     <section id="main" class="....." data-section="....." data-step="">  

            @Html.Partial("ValidationSummary") 

            @Html.Partial("SharedPartialView", Model, new ViewDataDictionary {.....})          

     </section> 

}
```

And JS is included in master file. (Main view has Layout for this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

    $('input.date').watermark('dd/mm/yyyy');

    $('input.date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        maxDate: 0, 
        onClose: function () { $(this).valid(); } 
    });    

    $('input.time').watermark('hh:mm');
    $('input.time').timeEntry();

</script>
```

The controller is just: when validation fails, return partial view ("SharedPartialView")

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView("SharedPartialView", ciShareModel); //model
```

These datepicker and watermark jquery do work when page initially loaded....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running the javascript again, after you load the partial view? - A script-block is only run when the page loads, so the  in your master page is only run when the master is loaded. When you do an ajax call, you need to run any javascript for  the partial view seperately.

Put this code in your partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input.date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            maxDate: 0, 
            onClose: function () { $(this).valid(); } 
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Although - I suggest instead of using `$('input.date')`, give your input element a unique ID/class, otherwise you will reset any data a user may have entered in other 'input.date' fields on the page. Use for ex: `$('input.partialView_Date)` and call your input field in the partial view: `<input type="text" class="partialView_Date" />`

Comment: Thanks for your help Rafael. For the class name, actually I do want all "date"-input to be calendar control. And for the partial view, is there any other way besides this "JS re-write"? As it looks a little bit tedious if each partial view needs to re-write JS. For example jQuery libraries needs to be re-include as well in PV.... am I right?

Comment: @Samuel: ah no - you don't need to re-include libraries, it's just the javascript execution that you need - and you don't necessarily need it in the partial view, but I think it's the easiest. Basically, `$('input.date').datepicker` runs when you load the page, but at that point, the html of your partial view doesn't exist yet. When you load the PV, you need to run the .datepicker function for the newly created html. The libraries are already available though, you just need to execute the function.

Comment: So $(document).ready() will run when the partial view is loaded via ajax?

Comment: @ametren - yes, but only the $(document).ready() that you placed in the partial view. It will not fire on the parent-page.