# refreshing partial view doesn't rerun jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have previously read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226479/ajax-return-partial-view-lost-javascript) and yet still it doesn't work in my situation.

When my partial view is reloaded, the jquery nested within the partial view no longer works.

I'm calling the ajax via:

```
$('#refreshPage').click(function () {
            $('#tabMain-6').html("");
            $.get('@Url.Action("Index", "Allocations")', function (data) {
               // alert(data);
                $("#tabMain-6").html(data);
            });
        });
```

From clicking my button 'refeshPage'.

I have other Jquery on my page, but once this ajax is run, the jquery within my partial view is no longer happy to 'rerun'

I have used

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
```

within my partial view, and yet the javascript/jquery won't run?

All my scripts are nested within these .ready blocks, so i'm not sure as to why it's failing here.

any ideas?

Comment: getting any console errors???

Comment: @Kartikeya not that i'm aware of (chrome console reports nothing). The page *loads*, just without the j/s from being run (hence the likes of telerik controls not being rendered/dynamic styling not running/etc

Comment: The elements loaded by the AJAX callback are new elements. They do not have the event handlers bound. You need to bind them again, or, better, use event delegation with jQuery's `on` method.

Comment: @lonesomeday, You kind of lost me at the second sentence :S. I know it's quite rude/rookie/annoying/demanding, but could you possibly provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a question that has been asked a thousand times on jQuery. I understand why, because it's not especially intuitive.

Let's run through what you do.

First, you load an HTML file. Your browser turns your HTML into a DOM structure, with a tree of elements and other nodes.

Then, you run some Javascript/jQuery. This binds event handlers to your elements. For instance, it might bind a function that runs on a `click` event to an `a` element. It's important to note that you first select a collection of elements and then bind the function to them.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    console.log('a link was clicked');
});
```

This first finds all the `a` elements that currently exist, then binds the function to them. Note "that currently exist".

Then, you reload your HTML. You now replace the old elements, which had the event handlers bound, with new elements. These do not have the  event handlers bound, because the elements did not exist when you ran the Javascript.

So what's the solution? Well, one option would be to run your event-binding code every time the page content changes. This will probably work, but it's cumbersome and inefficient, especially on complex pages. The better option is to use something called **event delegation**. This uses a feature of Javascript called "bubbling": when an event is fired on an element, all the ancestor elements are also notified of that event. So, in our example, a `div` element that contains the `a` element will also be told of the click on the `a` element.

What we can do, therefore, is bind our event handler on an ancestor element of the elements that we're replacing. So we bind a `click` handler to `#tabMain-6`, perhaps, in your question. This element is not replaced, so the event handler will remain. (Often people use the `document` element, because it is never replaced, but it's better to use an element as near as possible to where the event originates.) We then can then test the event to see if it originated on an element that matches a selector.

You can do all of this yourself, but jQuery makes it very easy with the `on` function.

```
$('#tabMain-6').on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert('a link inside #tabMain-6 was clicked');
});
```

This will carry on working no matter how many times the content of `#tabMain-6` is replaced. The first argument is the event type; the third argument is the event handler function. The second argument is the crucial one: it is a selector that tests the element where the event originated *at that moment*.

You will need to work out precisely what this looks like in your code, but event delegation is probably the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation! after reading this, I actually think I get it! Plus your example makes sense, with details of what arguments/selectors go where. I'm sure I can adapt this for my other pages as well! cheers.